# How to traverse G (networkx multidigraph) in a loop to export as OSM or in some Database?

Tags: python, openstreetmap, osmnx

How to traverse G (networkx multidigraph) in a loop to export as OSM or in some Database? 
or is there any built in function to export it as json ?

Answer (score 1):

You can export a graph to GraphML, ESRI ShapeFile, or geopandas GeoDataFrame using OSMnx's  [save_load module](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#module-osmnx.save_load), see also [this example of use](https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx-examples/blob/master/notebooks/05-example-save-load-networks-shapes.ipynb). GeoDataFrames themselves can be dumped to JSON/GeoJSON and Shapefiles can be converted to GeoJSON with [ogr2ogr](https://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html).